# Jquery Waypoints offset

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to figure out how i can make the div to slide out and slide in back when the offset is met using jQuery waypoint, I'm also using dan eden CSS animation. This is the code i have made but the problem is when i scroll back up the div won't slide In back even though i set the offset to 100%

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(".slide_copy1").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass(" slideInLeft").removeClass("slideOutRight");      
},{offset:'100%'})

$(".slide_copy1").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("slideOutRight").removeClass("slideInLeft");       
},{offset:'0%'})
```

UPDATED POST -

```
$(".slide_copy1").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass(" slideInLeft").removeClass("slideOutRight");
},{offset: '100%' function(){
    $(this).addClass("slideOutRight").removeClass("slideInLeft");   
}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply two different changes in both directions you need 4 waypoints; in this way you can 'define' the zone were the modification should take place. I've created a small Fiddle as an example, in this case the div become blue between 25% and 75% of the window height: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/mLAr2/

```
$("div").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("blue").removeClass("red");      
},{offset:'25%'});

$("div").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("red").removeClass("blue");      
},{offset:'24%'});

$("div").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("blue").removeClass("red");       
},{offset:'74%'});

$("div").waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("red").removeClass("blue");      
},{offset:'75%'});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and also the neat fiddle. Was thinking another way to shorten this code

Comment: You can use a function as an argument for `offset`, within the function you can check both boundaries; in this way you can return using only two waypoints

Comment: no like this `$("div").waypoint(function(){ ... },{offset: function(){ ... }})`

Comment: I think i'm doing something wrong with your current answer. please see the updated post

Comment: I made a mistake, actually you _can_ use a function as `offset` value but this function is evaluated only once and not during the scroll, I think you still need 4 waypoints to achieve the result